# Permission to Access External Storage Denied in AndroidTest

Tags: android, opencv, permissions, storage

Before I begin explaining my question, I have to mention that I am new to Android development.

I am trying to write a program for Android which uses OpenCV's Java API for some data processing. I am developing unit tests for classes that implement algorithms and these classes are not related to any activity yet. In other words, I just want to test the functionality of methods before dealing with activities.

Because I need to have access to OpenCV libraries, I have written my unit test under androidTest in Android Studio. The files that contain data and need to be read in the program are copied to /sdcard/DIR and /storage/emulated/0/DIR. I have added the following permission to AndroidManifest.xml to grant access to external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, when I try to read files from external storage I get 
`open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. Note that I concatenate the path returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` with the name of data files and use a `FileInputStream` later on to read contents of the files.

I have seen similar questions and answers that mention access should be granted at runtime for APIs above 23. But because I don't have any activities for my methods, I guess I can't request permission at runtime.

1. Are there any other directories I can use to place my data files that do not require these permissions? I thought of `assets` as an option, but I am assuming that assets are put in the final apk and if I need to change files for a different data, I have to create a new apk every time.
2. How should I grant access to /sdcard without having any activity that asks user for a permission at runtime?
3. Can I do local testing instead of androidTest by installing OpenCV libraries on my linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary workaround for this issue. I designed a button in MainActivity that when pressed, asks user for permission to access the directory where my files are located at. Afterwards, I could run the androidTest unit tests without facing the exception because this permission needs to be granted only once.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but android doesn't provide that type of access 
you will need to create a activity to launch the application

I think if you are using marshmallow device then you will be needing to ask the permission to read and write external storage at runtime

you can refer at the following liink
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //do the things} else {
    requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
      AnyNumber);
```

Later catch those requests in

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == AnyNumber) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could permission be granted without having a UI? Doesn't requestPermissions require a UI?

Comment: It was possible for earlier versions of Android, but after marshmallow permissions will be dynamic and not asked while installation